# How do I make all the container sizes same and also how to set the images in a proper way?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

**IMAGE :**

[image: image1]

How do I set a standard container size and also how do I size the images in a proper way so that the clarity of the images dont disturb and also gives a good look.

The images are of different sizes so dont know what to do exactly, should I set them to a standard size? or is there any better way?

**CODE :**

```
  <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row ">

          {% for job in jobs.all %}
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
              <img class = "card-img-top" src = "{{job.image.url}}">
              <div class="card-body" >
                <p class="card-text" >{{job.summary}}</p>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: When using photos, you must take into consideration the size of your original photo. If you resize the photo outside of a photo editing software, you can get pixelation. This is common when resizing too drastically. Edit your photo so it is close to the size you will be using in pixels. Then it will look clear and precise. Also use an RGB color format instead of CMYK. These will help ensure your photos look clear and have no pixelation. If you do not have PhotShop, Gimp is free and has great editing tools that will allow you to edit size and format.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstap 4 add a class property

```
<img class = "card-img-top" src = "{{job.image.url}}" class="img-fluid" >
```